# Jquery animation cutting the border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have made a banner using Jquery animation and its working fine except image effect is cutting the border. It should come up within a container but i have tried to fix it but the problem is still the same. Here is a link [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cbhsr/3/)

```
    <div id="mainContainer">
                <img id="introImg" src="http://blog.room34.com/wp-content/uploads/underdog/logo.thumbnail.png"/>


        <div id="text1" style="position:absolute;">Striped Bag</div><br />
        <div id="text2" style="position:absolute;">$14</div><br />
        <div id="text3" style="position:absolute;">Sale $25</div><br />
</div>

 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#text1").animate({ left: "+=30" }, 500);
        $("#text1").animate({ left: "-=20" }, 200);
        $("#text2").delay(300).animate({ left: "+=30" }, 500);
        $("#text2").animate({ left: "-=20" }, 200);
        $("#text3").delay(400).animate({ left: "+=30" }, 500);
        $("#text3").animate({ left: "-=20" }, 200);
     $("#introImg").animate({width: "100px"}, 1000);
    });


#mainContainer{
     background-image:url('https://secure-ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingRes/Site-8188/Type-0/5fefb401-b187-4d82-b4db-cbd2ef29cc48.gif');
    width:300px;
    height:250px;
    border: 1px solid #5e6a71;
border-style:solid;
border-width:5px;
 border-color:#BACAE4;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative

}

#introImg{
    position:absolute;
    top:60px;
    left:170px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:300px;
    opacity: 100;
}

#text1, #text2, #text3
{
     margin:60px 8px;

}

#ctaBtn{
    top:200px;
    left:25px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want. Would you be able to explain it a bit more?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the problem is? Are you not wanting the image to be hidden by the border?

Comment: Are you looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/Cbhsr/5/??

Comment: i have updated a code can you see the change how bag image is coming out i want it to be inside border. Is it clear ?

Comment: no Milind see my updated version

Comment: @user3196720: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Cbhsr/7/

Comment: @user3196720 - Maybe something like this? again, your explanation isn't clear enough for us to assist you properly. http://jsfiddle.net/Cbhsr/8/

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the parent element `#mainContainer` has a background image with border and that background image is always below the `#mainContainer` content. You can fix this bu removing the border from the backgound image and increase the border size for `#mainContainer` to have the same style.

And there is another option:
- change `#mainContainer` html to:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
<img class="bgImg" src="https://secure-ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingRes/Site-8188/Type-0/5fefb401-b187-4d82-b4db-cbd2ef29cc48.gif" />
<img style="width: 100px;" id="introImg" src="http://blog.room34.com/wp-content/uploads/underdog/logo.thumbnail.png">
<div id="text1" style="position: absolute; left: 10px;">Striped Bag</div><br>
<div id="text2" style="position: absolute; left: 10px;">$14</div><br>
<div id="text3" style="position: absolute; left: 10px;">Sale $25</div><br>
```

and css styles:

```
#mainContainer{
 /*background-image:url('https://secure-ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingRes/Site-8188/Type-0/5fefb401-b187-4d82-b4db-cbd2ef29cc48.gif');*/ /* remove the background image from the CSS */
width:300px;
height:250px;
border: 1px solid #5e6a71;
border-style:solid;
border-width:5px;
border-color:#BACAE4;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
z-index: 10000000;
}

#introImg{
position:absolute;
top:60px;
left:170px;
border-radius: 50%;
width:300px;
opacity: 100;
z-index: 2; /* new property */
}

/* new class */
.bgImg {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;}
```